# Как десериализовать компонент из XML?

Tags: xml, java

Вот у меня есть несколько xml файлов, в которых хранится следующее:

```
<Сampaign>
<numberOfHits> 1000 </numberOfHits>
<кegion>
    <id> region1 </id>
</кegion>
<budget> 500 </budget>
    <period> 3 </period>
<intervalOfTime> 5 </intervalOfTime>
<site>
    <siteId> 1 </siteId>
</site>
</Сampaign>
```

И есть класс

```
public class Campaign {

    private int compaignId;
    private Target target;
    private int numberOfHits;
    private double budget;
    private Period intervalOfTime;
    private ArrayList < Site > sites;
}
```

Как мне по такому xml файлу получить объект класса `campaign`

Comment: XStream [погуглите]( http://www.google.com/m?q=java%20xstream%20example&client=ms-opera-mobile&channel=new).  
[Годная статья]( http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-xstream/) с примером использования.

Comment: sax, dom парсеры

Comment: а какой из них проще для понимая?

Comment: а это не обычный парсинг?

Comment: sax - быстрее и проще, dom - универсальнее

Comment: мне нужно будет заниматься десереализацией только таких файлов, думаю sax подойдет...

Comment: в java есть стандартные [средства][1]


  [1]: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-convert-a-javabean-to-an-xml-string-using-xmlencoder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря чем был сериализован исходный Java объект. Если известен сериализатор, то он же сам и пусть десериализует. Если не было никакого сериализатора, то тогда надо брать в руки что-то из области SAX и парсить XML самостоятельно.

**Update:** Вообще судя по стилю очень похоже на работу сериализатора [XStream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XStream). По крайней мере следы применения рефлексии в названиях тегов видны.

Comment: @Barmaley, а есть ли разница чем сериализован в текущее представление? (Чисто из своего интереса, т.к. предполагаю что это не имеет значения)

Comment: Конечно имеет значения. Каждый сериализатор пишет в своем формате, скажем применяет свои именования тегов или их вложенность, наличие/отстутствие атрибутов и проч.

Comment: @Barmaley, но сериализатор в любом случае за пределы референса не уходит, а если соответсвует референсу, то проблем с десериализацией возникнуть не должно. Или Вы к тому, что результат десериализации может отличаться от исходного, не сериализированного представления?

Comment: если правильно настроиш свои парсер - отличий недолжно быть

Comment: @Barmaley, Вообще этот xml файл я сам руками набил... ) Сериализатора нет.
Кстати сериализотор еще придется сооружать..

Comment: ток юзай json